# How to setup IP restriction for Azure Web App via Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to setup IP restrictions in Azure for both an App Service and a Web App. From the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions I got the impression that setting the IP restriction on an App Service level should be sufficient and cover all possible Web Apps that the App Service might contain.

However, I find myself having to setup IP restrictions on both levels e.g. App Service and Web App.

Does anyone know if it's possible to setup IP restrictions on an App Service level and have it "apply" for all Web Apps?

Comment: By App Service, do you mean App Service Plan?

Comment: Hi @juunas, no, I mean App Service e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/media/app-service-ip-restrictions/ip-restrictions.png

Comment: Okay, well, App Service and Web App are kind of the same thing when it comes to configuring them in the Portal. App Service = Web Apps + Logic Apps + API Apps + Mobile Apps.

Comment: Right, my understanding is that an App Service is a "container" for Web Apps, API Apps etc. so having to setup IP restrictions in both places seems odd. I managed to figure out how to do it though - if you setup IP restrictions on the App Service, it will be inherited in the Web App. I was re-deploying my app to see if it could be due to the changes not going through but during the deploy it suddenly reflected the changes so it could just be that it takes quite a while to propagate from the App Service to the Web App.

Comment: You mean app service plan :D that's what the container is called :)